# No route to host : ssh Error

Tags: 12.04, networking, ssh

I have a laptop and a PC (me@172.16.13.151) , I usually connect the laptop to PC via ssh. But now when I try `ssh -X me@172.16.13.151` , it is showing the following error `ssh: connect to host 172.16.13.151 port 22: No route to host`. What could be the possible problem ?

Output of `ifconfig` is the following:

```
eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:41:38:0d:bb:a2
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:1750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:134949 (134.9 KB)  TX bytes:134949 (134.9 KB)

wlan0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:df:9a:76:18:1e
inet addr:172.16.101.213  Bcast:172.16.111.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
inet6 addr: fe80::d2df:9aff:fe76:181e/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:595855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:37917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:138691381 (138.6 MB)  TX bytes:4733835 (4.7 MB)
```

output of `route` is the following :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.96.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
172.16.96.0     *               255.255.240.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: Generally it's recommended to redact the real ip addresses in your question

Comment: `@grooveplex` Here I don't have any control over the PC right now.